# Can't definitively delete certain records

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL table from which I try to remove 2 different records through phpmyadmin.
It succeeds and when I hit browse again, the results of the query are updated: the records are removed.

A bit later though, the same records reappear, with a different ID (which is my PRIMARY key).

I searched my public folder for "insert" and didn't find a statemnt which would insert these 2 records.

How can this be possible? Is there a way to find out how the records get added back again in certain log files?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a known issue where records are inserted without any action. ... Sorry, this is not possible. Your code is executing twice.

Comment: I don't have any code removing the records because I use phpmyadmin to remove them

Answer (score 1):

Is your `id` AUTOINCREMENTed field? If yes, then, you don't delete your records.
If no so, there are two variants: 1. you don't delete you records, 2. you insert them again.

Comment: yes my id is autoincremented. can you explain me why my records aren't deleted?

Comment: I remove the records through phpmyadmin, by clicking on the red cross :)

Comment: Is this server part of a MySQL replication ring?

Comment: @Marc: Thanks for answering, but I have only one EC2 instance running at Amazon web services, so I don't think so.